# Getting multiple height values from a single responsive element

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a HTML element that varies in height dependent on what media query is being called.

Is there any way that I can store the height of the element for both queries on document load, if the css is `height: auto;` ?

Comment: If you want to do this for some effect I believe using css3 transitions instead will save you the trouble of saving it's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the [`$(selector).height( value )`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to get or set the height

Comment: I do, but this will only get the value of the current height, I need a way to get the height if the element is using a different media query, too.

Comment: but when the browser will be resized, the height value will change, and you can get this with the .resize(), http://api.jquery.com/resize/